# Prove that there always exists integer greater than $\sqrt{2n}$ and smaller than $\sqrt{5n}$ if $n$ is an integer greater than 0.

Tags: proof-writing, integers

I know that $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. I want to prove that there exists such $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ that it is greater than $\sqrt{2n}$ and smaller than $\sqrt{5n}$? I can do it by showing inequalities for $n^2$, $(n-1)^2$, $(n+1)^2$ etc. within some subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, but is there a way to show it briefly for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$?

Comment: Follow up question: Show that there is always a prime number between $\sqrt{2n}$ and $\sqrt{5n}$ (boundary included).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: For any $a<b$ with $b-a>1$, there exists some integer strictly between $a$ and $b$. (See if you can prove this.) Now, all you need is
$$\sqrt{5n}-\sqrt{2n}>1.$$
For which $n$ does this hold?

Comment: Oh I didn't see it in that light that we can just show that the difference between those two numbers is greater than 1, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{5n}-\sqrt{2n}=\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2})$$

$$\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{10}-2>\sqrt{9}-2=1$$

This proves that the gap between $\sqrt{2n}$ and $\sqrt{5n}$ will always be greater than $1$ for $n \geq 2$, so there must be an integer between them. All that's left is to check the special case $n=1$, and $\sqrt{5}>\sqrt{4}=2>\sqrt{2}$

Comment: great you are right, thanks!

Comment: If you're satisfied, then please accept an answer so the question is closed.